# comparing forloop variables to a number

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Products</a>
            </li>
            {% for x in cat %}
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{x.name}}</a>
            </li>
            {% if forloop.counter >3%}
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">More</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{x.name}}</a>
                
              </div>
            </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
          
            
          </ul>
```

So what i want here is the objects in the for loop counter be more that three then all should come  in the dropdown menu which but it is not working as of now and giving me this error what is the best way to handle this problem

```
Could not parse the remainder: '>3' from '>3'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '>3' from '>3'
Exception Location: C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\e-com-test\core\hienv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 692, in __init__
Python Executable:  C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\e-com-test\core\hienv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\saran\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\e-com-test\\core',
 'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\saran\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\e-com-test\\core\\hienv',
 'C:\\Users\\saran\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\e-com-test\\core\\hienv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 10 Dec 2021 13:32:32 +0
```

Comment: Hi, you tried to do {% if forloop.counter > 3 %} instead of {% if forloop.counter >3%}?

Comment: Try adding a space between > and 3 ({% if forloop.counter > 3 %})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding spaces

```
{% if forloop.counter > 3 %}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working